# Alamofire error stringSerialization UTF8

Tags: swift, utf-8, character-encoding, alamofire

I am doing **two** different html requests with Alamofire, both work fine using a browser and seem to return the same html source, however using Alamofire one of them fails to decode the data response to string.

Could someone help me understand why? NOTICE the small difference in the urls is the second url has an **'n'** at the end

```
let urlString1 = "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/andalusia"
let urlString2 = "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/andalusian"

Alamofire.request(urlString<1 or 2>).responseString { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        // Do something with html string
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Results:

- urlString1 fetches html string perfect
- urlString2 prints error:
  `Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.stringSerializationFailed(Unicode (UTF-8)))`

Comment: You defined urlString1 and urlString2 but then used urlString in the network call. What's urlString defined as?

Comment: That was for illustration purposes only. The actual code uses both strings. urlString1 succeeds, and urlString2 fails.